# Login using cy.request() results in 400: Bad Request error

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

In my Cypress tests, I try to login to my application programatically using cy.request() to avoid logging in with UI every time (as described in Cypress documentation https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/testing-your-app.html#Logging-in)

This is my code:

```
cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'localhost',
        body: {
            AccountName: 'accountname',
            Password: 'password'
        }
    })
```

In response, I'm expecting to get a session Cookie that I can set and use for my tests.

However, when I run the above code in Cypress I get:

> cy.request() failed on:

> localhost

> The response we received from your web server was:

> 400: Bad Request

And also under response:

> Body: Invalid client type

How should I write the request body to get status 200 and successfully get the session Cookie I am expecting?
When I login manually and verify Network tab of my browser, everything works fine.

Comment: Hey @mariobrosbb can you replace url with something like `http://localhost:8080`, change the port number whichever is applicable and give it a try.

Comment: That's not the case, I replaced real url with dummy 'localhost' for the purpose of this post (I don't want to show the real url here) so it's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Ok. Is your endpoint using OAuth ? If yes then you have to replace `body: {AccountName: 'accountname',Password: 'password'}` with `auth: {'username': 'username','password': 'password'}`